# Using rabbitmq to provide to provide data to incoming server request

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to get an idea evaluated by bigger group on technical side.
I have an api in .net 6 with just couple of endpoints that when a request is coming I want to block that request until an information is fetched from other systems via rabbit mq.

It somewhat looks like this:
Request --> api --> injects a command to another system ABC queue (not rabbit) -> message is consumed by ABC --> ABC drops a response to rabbitMQ

What I'm thinking of doing is using either headers or topics with routes (based on endpoint url) to correlate the incoming request with resulting message.

There is a timeout on the request to API and would only wait until that timeout is exhausted (fair to assume that client will be configured accordingly) and also there is only one request coming at a time.

My plan is create a rabbitMQ channel when a request comes up and keep that channel up until request is completed or timedout.

Are there some better approaches or ideas that I should look?

*I have no way to fetch the information directly from ABC and ABC has no api.*

Comment: frequent creation of channel is a bad idea since it is a very resource intensive operation , instead you should create the channel for the first request and you are better off following the HTTP longpoll approach.